# Why do I get this unexpected behaviour for the cv2.getRectSubPix center?

Tags: python, opencv

I am using `cv2.getRectSubPix`, and I am getting some unexpected results when setting the center:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

src = np.reshape(range(4), (2, 2)).astype('float32')
print(src)
>> [[0. 1.]
>>  [2. 3.]]

patch = cv2.getRectSubPix(src, patchSize=(1, 1), center=(0, 1))
print(patch)
>> [[2.]]
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga77576d06075c1a4b6ba1a608850cd614), the calculation should be the following:

```
patch[x, y] = src[x + center.x - (dst.cols  - 1) * 0.5, y + center.y - (dst.rows - 1) * 0.5]
patch[0, 0] = src[0 +     0    - (    1     - 1) * 0.5, 0 +     1    - (    1    - 1) * 0.5]
patch[0, 0] = src[0, 1]
```

However, `patch[0, 0] = 2`, while `src[0, 1] = 1`.

It seems like you have to switch `center.y` and `center.x`, and everything works out. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per default, NumPy stores array elements in [row-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order). So, the correct order to access elements would be `src[y, x]` or `patch[y, x]`. Of course, that's extra confusing when `getRectSubPix` parameters `patchSize=(w, h)` and `center=(x, y)` are given in that order.

Here's a small, partial re-implementation of `getRectSubPix` to follow the linked calculation properly:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np


# Attention: Interpolation for non-integer coordinates is omitted here!
def getRectSubPix_NoInterpolation(src, patchSize, center):
    dst_cols, dst_rows = patchSize
    center_x, center_y = center
    p = np.zeros((dst_rows, dst_cols), src.dtype)
    for y in range(dst_rows):                                           # Iterate rows first
        for x in range(dst_cols):                                       # Iterate columns second
            p[y, x] = src[int(y + center_y - (dst_rows - 1) * 0.5),     # Access y first
                          int(x + center_x - (dst_cols - 1) * 0.5)]     # Access x second
    return p


src = np.reshape(range(6), (3, 2)).astype('float32')
print(src)
#  [[0. 1.]
#   [2. 3.]
#   [4. 5.]]

ps = (1, 1)
c = (1, 2)          # That's src[2, 1] = 5!

cv2_patch = cv2.getRectSubPix(src, ps, c)
print(cv2_patch)
#  [[5.]]

patch = getRectSubPix_NoInterpolation(src, ps, c)
print(patch)
#  [[5.]]
```